# How can i create a vertical tabbed form for contact us in my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

i want to create a vertical tab for contact us that on clicking should open the form

how can i do that??

I am creating a website in asp.net!

Comment: Create a form on the page. Position it off screen with CSS, by default. Write some javascript that'll animate it in on click. Have a go and post a question when you get stuck!

Comment: First be specific. Show what you did. Post some code what you. State your question clearly.

Comment: @johnnycardy http://jsfiddle.net/Du665/ this is what i have done uptil date

Comment: @user3152634 put your code here from jsfiddle. if jsiddle down others cannot figure out your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.I guess this is what you are asking for since you didnt provide any code:

For the element containing contact link add this CSS:

**CSS for rotate :**

```
transform:rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/Du665/2/

**JQuery:**

```
$('.rotate').click(function(){
    $('#Cform').toggle('slow');
});
```

*Response to comment:*

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/Du665/4/

Comment: (http://jsfiddle.net/Du665/)
This is what i have done uptil date

Comment: Ok i will see it and update my answer later

Comment: m unable to add other controls  in that!! like <input type="text" />

Comment: its was a great help!! :) :)

Comment: the code isnt working when i included it in my website.. i mean when i clicked Bulk order the jquery code isnt working

Comment: div cannot be nested within a ul

Comment: Include this in your head section `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js'></script>` for using JQuery

Comment: Why use `<ul>` & `<li>` when you can do the work with `<div>`?

Comment: You must connect to internet while using `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js`. Still not running post your full code of that page.